# useState is not re-rendering after sorting the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, web

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
const App= () =>{

const bubble = [9,8,6,5,3,1];
const Visual = () =>{
    const [list, setBubbleSort] = useState(bubble);
    const bubbleSort = () =>{
        const newArray = [...list];
        let n=6;
        for(let i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(let j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
                if(newArray[j]>newArray[j+1])
                {
                    let temp = newArray[j];
                    newArray[j] = newArray[j+1];
                    newArray[j+1] = temp;
                }
                setBubbleSort([...newArray]);
    };
return(
 <button onClick={bubbleSort}>Click me</button>);
```

---

the initial array is rendered but, when button is clicked it is not re-rendering the sorted array

Comment: @prabhatdhakar Please rework your code format. Currently it's very hard to see where one component starts and the other ends. Post full components even if they are stripped down to the bare minimum. Don't expect us to know what *errors* are intentional and which might be the ones that are the source for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is confusing because of your lack of `{}` and poor code indentation.

Here's a working example. Note that `App` calls `Visual` with the array. `Visual` isn't a component *inside* `App` which is what your code suggests.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const bubble = [9,8,6,5,3,1];
  return <Visual bubble={bubble} />;
}

function Visual({ bubble }) {

  const [list, setBubbleSort] = useState(bubble);

  function bubbleSort() {

    const newArray = [...list];

    let n = 6;

    for (let i = 0;i < n; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
        if (newArray[j] > newArray[j + 1]) {
          let temp = newArray[j];
          newArray[j] = newArray[j + 1];
          newArray[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }

    setBubbleSort([...newArray]);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={bubbleSort}>Click me</button>
      <div>{list}</div>
    </div>
  );

}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: it is working  <div>{list}</div> but <div>{bubble}</div> is not working, what is the reason?

Comment: Because bubble is not a state, and list is a state with initial value bubble. If you want to re-render in div, you need to use state